# environment variables in heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, production

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
const devConfig = {
 //config here
};
const prodConfig = {
//config here
};

export const firebaseInit = firebase.initializeApp(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' ? devConfig : prodConfig);
export const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
```

i have this firebase config file.

in my procfile i have: `web: NODE_ENV=production node ./src/server/index.js`

in my webpack i have:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV) || '"development"'
        }
    }),
```

and in my package.json i have:

```
"start": "node src/server/index.js",
"start:production": "NODE_ENV=production ./node_modules/.bin/webpack && node src/server/index.js",
"start:dev": "NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/webpack && node src/server/index.js",
```

and in my heroku app settings i have gone and set `NODE_ENV` as the key with `production` as the value

i have deployed the master code after pushing my code up. yet when the app starts up it still logs up in my console as 'development mode'. what am i missing to start the app in production? i can do it locally just not on heroku

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: @Mark_M i have already done that as stated above

Comment: I don't see where you are calling something like `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION = production `

Comment: it says `You can also edit config vars on your app’s settings tab on Dashboard:` which is what i have done. is that not a choice between the two options?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if any of this fixes your issue, but hopefully it helps.

1) Could Heroku be picking up the "start" script before the Procfile which doesn't have "NODE_ENV=production" in it? I don't use a Procfile, I just rely on the start script, so not sure.

2) Does NODE_ENV=production definitely carry through after an && in start:production script call? It might be worth copying and pasting it to before the node script too, just to be sure.

3) JSON.stringify will resolve an empty string as true so best to put || "development" inside the JSON.stringify function, like this:

```
'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
```

4) You have single and double quotes around '"development"' which would create the string with the double quotes which would be a different string to just the word development.